# Receptacle daisy chained with both cables live

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, circuit

I live in a 1955 house and am exploring the electrical.  Discovered an outlet daisy-chained on an ungrounded circuit.  I turned off the power and disconnected the hot and neutral of one of the cables.  Turned power back on and both cables at outlet are live.  So power is being fed from both cables?  How is this possible?  And wouldn't this be dangerous?

Comment: Did you test there was no power at all at the outlet after turning off the breaker?  Is there tabs(short pieces connecting the two screws) still there?  If not then quite possible that the two halves of the outlet is fed by two breakers.  Can be a MWBC circuit with one neutral or two separate circuits.  Done so you can use a toaster and kettle on the same outlet/receptacle without tripping the breaker/burning out the fuse.  It is dangerous so that is why code changed to use handle ties on the two breakers.

Comment: How are you checking for power? Van you upload pictures showing where the wires connect to the receptacle?

Comment: Could be (improper in the US, proper in some other parts of the world as a "ring circuit") connected to one fuse/breaker in two directions, could be connected to two different breakers in multiple ways, several of which are perfectly legit, but may not be done to current standards in a 1955 dwelling which was before some changes to make those safer were implemented in code.

Comment: It is a duplex receptacle and not split.  Single breaker.  I discovered a pullchain light that is now off when one cable has been disconnected from the other.  I removed the receptacle altogether to take it out of the equation.  Tested the wires using a multimeter.  One set is definitely dead.  So this brings up a new question.  I was using a contactless tester.  I have tested cables adjacent to each other without interference from each other.  Yet here it seems that because they are in the same box, the proximity causes both to be tested live?  Even downstream from the box?

Comment: Incidentally, they had replaced several receptacles including this one and jumpered ground and neutral.  So I'm gradually undoing all of that.  What is a good tool to use to remove backstabbed wires?

Comment: If you are replacing the receptacles with new ones, there's the brute force approach: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/267259/18078

Comment: They are new, but tamper resistant.  So I am tempted to replace them with non-TR.  We are older and childless, and have no patience to spend a half hour trying to plug in something.

Comment: @MrTrashcan1 The quality newer receptacles, commercial/spec grade and better from a major brand, have improved TR mechanisms, and TR is required by code now almost everywhere. The contactless testers will definitely give false positive readings sometimes if near another energized wire.  You will almost certainly want a freshly-stripped wire end, so I would just snip the wires rather than trying to un-backstab them.

Comment: where are you in the world? in the UK a ringmain is common and legal, but the ring must remain intact,